# Extend LUKS partition

Tags: luks

I have built a kali live usb 32GB with encrypted persistence.

Now I have copied the 32GB content to a 64GB usb device using the dd command, and everything is working fine on the new 64 GB device.

Since the 64 GB stick has free available space, I want to expand the encrypted (LUKS) partition. Unfortunately, so far I have no reliable information on how to implement this partition extension.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe https://www.lisenet.com/2013/extend-an-encrypted-luks-partition/ https://superuser.com/questions/1247499/extending-ext4-linux-partition-kali-linux

Comment: See my own comment about the solution. Anyway, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to resize the new 64GB device, taking in consideration the information found [here](https://www.lisenet.com/2013/extend-an-encrypted-luks-partition/).

For the sake of completeness, I have included the output of the single commands.

1. Start kali-live system using the original usb device (32GB).
2. Inserted the usb stick (64GB) containing the LUKS partition to be modified (expanded).
3. Using **GParted**, create a new partition (8 GB), saving the remaining free space for other use.
   [image]
   [image]
4. Delete LUKS partition, delete partition to be added (8GB), and create new one (size old_LUKS_partition + 8GB)

   ```
   sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

   Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.37.2).

   Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
   Be careful before using the write command.


   Command (m for help): p
   Disk /dev/sdb: 59.63 GiB, 64023257088 bytes, 125045424 sectors
   Disk model: Extreme         
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disklabel type: dos
   Disk identifier: 0x59536a28

   Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
   /dev/sdb1  *          64  7866239  7866176  3.8G 17 Hidden HPFS/NTFS
   /dev/sdb2        7866240  7867711     1472  736K  1 FAT12
   /dev/sdb3        7868416 60088319 52219904 24.9G 83 Linux
   /dev/sdb4       60088320 76865535 16777216    8G 83 Linux

   Command (m for help): d
   Partition number (1-4, default 4): 

   Partition 4 has been deleted.

   Command (m for help): d
   Partition number (1-3, default 3): 

   Partition 3 has been deleted.

   Command (m for help): n
   Partition type
      p   primary (2 primary, 0 extended, 2 free)
      e   extended (container for logical partitions)
   Select (default p): p
   Partition number (3,4, default 3): 
   First sector (7867712-125045423, default 7868416): 
   Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (7868416-125045423, default 125045423): -22.9G

   Created a new partition 3 of type 'Linux' and of size 32.9 GiB.
   Partition #3 contains a crypto_LUKS signature.

   Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: N

   Command (m for help): w

   The partition table has been altered.
   Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
   Syncing disks.
   ```
5. Unlock the partition:

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb3 persistence
   Enter passphrase for /dev/sdb3:
   ```
6. Filesystem Check:

   ```
   sudo e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/persistence

   e2fsck 1.46.4 (18-Aug-2021)
   persistence: recovering journal
   Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
   Pass 2: Checking directory structure
   Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
   Pass 4: Checking reference counts
   Pass 5: Checking group summary information
   Free blocks count wrong (2400085, counted=2397778).
   Fix<y>? yes

   Free inodes count wrong (1243709, counted=1243712).
   Fix<y>? yes

   persistence: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
   persistence: 388288/1632000 files (6.2% non-contiguous), 4125614/6523392 blocks
   ```
7. Resize the Partition:

   ```
   sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/persistence

   resize2fs 1.46.4 (18-Aug-2021)
   Resizing the filesystem on /dev/mapper/persistence to 8613632 (4k) blocks.
   The filesystem on /dev/mapper/persistence is now 8613632 (4k) blocks long.
   ```
8. Final result of the running kali-live file system itself on the 64GB stick:
   [image]

I hope this can help people with similar problems.

Comment: I cannot imagine why you create an 8GB partition in `gparted` only to immediately delete it with `fdisk`. Also I'd recommend using `cfdisk` instead of `fdisk`, it's much more user friendly for resizing partitions and less likely to screw things up.  Deleting a partition and then re-creating it can cause nasty problems such as changing the UUID of a GPT table partition.

Comment: Can you explain what `dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are?

Comment: When creating the 8GB, the remaining free space is automatically calculated, which I subtract later when expanding (...(7868416-125045423, default 125045423): -22.9G) - so I make my life easier.


Yes, your suggestion is another one. It's a matter of taste, like everything in life. Many roads lead to Rome. :-)


/dev/sda -> encrypted persistent drive
/dev/sdb -> persistent drive


So I have the choice on booting which system to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you would normally extend a partition.

The LUKS header doesn't include the partition size and the partition is encrypted block by block. So when you extend the encrypted partition size, it should automatically extend the size of the mapped (unencrypted) partition.

However I'm not sure if LUKS will detect the change on mounted partitions. You might need to instruct it to resize active mappings with:

```
cryptsetup resize <mapping name>
```

Alternatively you could just close and re-open the mappings or reboot your system.

---

Just to avoid any doubt.  The normal way to extend a partition is to

- resize it in the partition table entry
- make the kernel discover the new size (usually happens implicitly, see below)
- resize the file system on the partition.

There are many tools which can resize partition table entry, but I'd recommend [cfdisk](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cfdisk.8.html).  It's by far the most user-friendly of such tools and even has a "resize" option (unlike `fdisk`).

Both `fdisk` and `cfdisk` prompt the kernel to discover the new size of the block device.  You don't normally need to do this yourself.  But if not, you can try `blockdev --rereadpt ...`.

To resize an ext2/3/4 file system you can use [resize2fs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/resize2fs.8.html).  Remember that this needs to be done to the unencrypted (mapped) block device, not to the encrypted partition that holds the LUKS volume.

Comment: It wasn't that easy. See my own comment about the solution. Anyway, Thank you!

Comment: @undigit it is that simple, but I didn't realise you were trying to use gparted which might complicate matters.

Comment: I will make use of your suggestion next time I'll try it. Anyway, I always want to achieve my goals and I use the tools that are available to me. Thank you!